# R: Repeat value until new value appears by group, only once first non-NA value appears

Tags: r, function, text, grouping, repeat

I'm looking to repeat values until a new value appears by group. I have a function that I found online a while back that almost does what I am looking for, but not quite. Here is that function:

```
    repeat.before <- function(x) {
  ind <- which(!is.na(x))
  ind_rep <- ind
  if (is.na(x[1])) {
    ind_rep <- c(min(ind), ind)
    ind <- c(1, ind)
  }
  rep(x[ind_rep], times = diff(c(ind, length(x) + 1)))
}
```

This function will successfully repeat the value until a new value appears, by group. The problem is, if the column starts with an NA, the following rows that exist before the first value, will end up taking that first value, instead of remaining NA. I'll illustrate what I mean with this example:

```
    group    location 
    A        NA
    A        NA
    A        New York
    A        NA
    A        NA
    B        Chicago
    B        NA
    B        Philly
    B        NA
```

The code above will output this:

```
    group    location 
    A        New York
    A        New York
    A        New York
    A        New York
    A        New York
    B        Chicago
    B        Chicago
    B        Philly
    B        Philly
```

Which, again, is very close to what I'm looking for, but not quite. This is the output I am seeking:

```
    group    location 
    A        NA
    A        NA
    A        New York
    A        New York
    A        New York
    B        Chicago
    B        Chicago
    B        Philly
    B        Philly
```

Basically, I don't want the "repeat" code to start working until it finds its first value. Until it does that, I'd like for the rows to stay NA. The purpose is so that rows don't get miscategorized, i.e. in the example above, the first two A rows should not be labelled New York.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is `fill` after grouping by 'group'.  Use the `fill` with `.direction` specified as 'up' or 'down' (default option).  Here, we need only 'down' option based on the expected output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  fill(location) 
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group location
#  <chr> <chr>   
#1 A     <NA>
#2 A     <NA>
#3 A     New York
#4 A     New York
#5 A     New York
#6 B     Chicago 
#7 B     Chicago 
#8 B     Philly  
#9 B     Philly
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
 "B"), location = c(NA, NA, "New York", NA, NA, "Chicago", NA, 
 "Philly", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with dplyr as I've only used it here and there. If I wanted to assign the result to a new column, for example "location_2", how would I do that using this method? Thanks for the quick response by the way!  EDIT: I believe this is tidyr, not dplyr?

Comment: @Jared doesn't want the first two rows to have 'New York' populated. I'd omit the line with fill up.

Comment: @JaredAnnibale  That is easy`, df1 %>% mutate(location2 = location) %>% group_by(group %>% fill(location2)`

Comment: @CTHall yep - if you change the direction to "down" it works perfectly. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `zoo` package using `na.locf` function.

```
library(zoo)
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B",
              "B"),
    location = c(NA, NA, "New York", NA, NA, "Chicago", NA,
                 "Philly", NA)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-9L))

df1$location2 <- na.locf(df1$location, na.rm = F)
df1

  group location location2
1     A     <NA>      <NA>
2     A     <NA>      <NA>
3     A New York  New York
4     A     <NA>  New York
5     A     <NA>  New York
6     B  Chicago   Chicago
7     B     <NA>   Chicago
8     B   Philly    Philly
9     B     <NA>    Philly
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
transform(df1,
          loc2 = ave(df1$location,
                     cumsum(!is.na(df1$location)),
                     FUN = function(x) x[1]))
#  group location     loc2
#1     A     <NA>     <NA>
#2     A     <NA>     <NA>
#3     A New York New York
#4     A     <NA> New York
#5     A     <NA> New York
#6     B  Chicago  Chicago
#7     B     <NA>  Chicago
#8     B   Philly   Philly
#9     B     <NA>   Philly
```